# How can I date old 3½" × 3½" pictures on Kodak paper with a "128B" mark?

Tags: product-photography

These are from approximately the 60s.

Back of pictures coded 128B

“Kodak paper”

Picture size inches 3 1/2 by 3 1/2

Comment: Can you post an image? Are you sure the words "Kodak paper" and the "128B" are part of the same mark?

Comment: @MichaelC Since markdown does odd things with whitespace, it wasn't clear, but in the original post here that's on a separate line. I added some newlines to make that more obvious, but, Jack, if you can expand more, we can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

Kodak papers marked on the back with A KODAK® PAPER are from 1961-1972. After that the mark became:

THIS PAPER
MANUFACTURED
BY KODAK

until the early 1990s. This isn't much, but it sounds like your guess about the 60s is pretty good, though they could also be from the early 1970s. The "128B" is a mystery--someone else may have encountered that, but I have not. In my experience (and I've done a lot of this), the image content itself is going to be key to getting a more precise date range.

Comment: The "128B" was almost certainly a mark left by the finisher who printed the photos.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that the date the paper was manufactured does not confirm the date a photo was printed. Kept refrigerated and sealed in its packaging, photo paper is usable for a long time.